# List Items Overlap Title in Navigation Bar When Browser Window is Shrunk

Tags: html, css

If you take the code and shrink your browser window you'll notice that the list items overlap the site title in the navigation bar which is annoying. Does anybody know how to fix this please?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Hyperdog Productions</title>
        <link href="css/stylesheet5.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="navigation_bar">
                    <p><a href="index.html" class="logo" id="home">Hyperdog Productions</a></p>
                    <ul class="navbar_list">
                        <li class="nav_list" id="about"><a class="nav_link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_list" id="short_films"><a class="nav_link" href="films.html">Short Films</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_list" id="cast/crew"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Cast/Crew</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_list" id="contact_us"><a class="nav_link" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li class="nav_list" id="other"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div> <!--End of NAV-->
                <main id="container">
                    <div id="container_wrapper">
                        <img class="container_background" src="images/bg.png" alt="Background" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer">
                    </div>
                </main> <!--End of Main-->
                <footer id="copyright">
                </footer>
        </div> <!--End of WRAPPER-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Lato-Regular";
src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.ttf");
src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.woff");
}

@font-face {
font-family: "PT-Sans";
src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.ttf");
src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.woff");
}

* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
/* Margin: 0; */
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 1500px;
overflow-x: none;
font-size: 0;
}

body {
font-size: 62.5%;
}

.wrapper {
height: 1500px;
}

#navigation_bar {
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

main {
height: 1300px;
}

#container_wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 865px;
background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 435px;
background-color: blue;
}

#copyright {
width: 100%;
height: 110px;
background-color: black;
}

.nav_link:link {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Lato-Regular", "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 3.7em !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ffffff;
}

.nav_link:hover {
color: grey;
}

.navbar_list {
float: right;
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 20%;
top: 16.25px;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar_list li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;
padding: 9px 12px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 10px;
display: inline;
}

.logo {
font-family: "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
color: #AF7817; /* #2C3539 */
margin: 0;
padding: 9px 12px;
float: left;
left: 20%;
position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 10px;
top: 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #000000;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you put these in a fiddle?

Comment: Where would you rather have the menu links be when the screen size is reduced?

Comment: they just dissapear. it's kind of hard to explain. but essentially, I would like them to just be hidden by the browser as it shrinks if that makes any sense

Comment: On my screen they overlap the title... http://i.stack.imgur.com/utP3W.png Would you rather them go below the title when the screen shrinks?

Comment: that's exactly what happens! I would just perfer they kind of dissapear. if you shrink a window with twitter or facebook small enough eventually the search bar and other icons aren't present. that's what i was hoping for, if you know a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following at the bottom of your CSS to drop the menu links lower down on the page and to center your title on the screen for smaller screen sizes. This is how I'd organize the page.

```
@media (max-width: 1750px) {
  .navbar_list {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: inherit;
    right: inherit;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  .logo {
    position: relative;
    left: inherit;
    float: inherit;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

#navigation_bar {
  text-align: center;
}
```

It will look like this on smaller screens:

[image]

Comment: thanks! however, do you know anyway to center the title and list items across the black navigation bar when the browser is shrunk. on my screen it looks great but there is a large black section to the right. is there anyway to center the list items and title across the entire thing? if that makes any sense?

Comment: I just updated my code. I made a mistake with your navigation bar. I used a dash instead of an underscore in the id. It works now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: one last thing. if I shrink the browser pretty slim/small the links go below the navigation bar. is there anything I can do about this, or is it what it is?

Comment: You could put `body{min-width: 575px;}` which won't let the website be smaller than 575px. That will keep the menu links from moving again at even smaller sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make them disappear

```
@media (max-width: 1530px) {
  .navbar_list {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Something like this WITH bootstrap.css

```
<div class="container">
<div id="navigation_bar" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p><a href="index.html" class="logo" id="home">Hyperdog Productions</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="navbar_list">
            <li class="nav_list" id="about"><a class="nav_link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav_list" id="short_films"><a class="nav_link" href="films.html">Short Films</a></li>
            <li class="nav_list" id="cast/crew"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Cast/Crew</a></li>
            <li class="nav_list" id="contact_us"><a class="nav_link" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="nav_list" id="other"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Other</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div> <!--End of NAV-->
    <main id="container">
        <div id="container_wrapper">
            <img class="container_background" src="images/bg.png" alt="Background" />
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </main> <!--End of Main-->
<footer id="copyright">
</footer>
</div> <!--End of WRAPPER-->
```

Comment: this kind of works, but do you know any other way that might allow the list items to be displayed before it reaches 1530px without overlapping?

Comment: The only thing that I don't like its to use position absolute...
I know that this works, but for me just seems as a workaround...
you should be able to use divs and float lefts or even bootstrap col-md-4 or something like this instead of position:absolute...

Comment: so I shouldn't use absolute positioning for the list items? also, i'm new to css and i've never used bootstrap before. sorry

Comment: Don't say sorry, there are people that use position absolute (many I would say...) I just don't feel the need to do it...

Anyway, you could set a min-width to the navigation-bar like 1530... so it wouldn't resize for less that 1530...

Bootstrap is great if you are starting....

all you have to do is create 

<div class="row"> AND put divs inside with the class col-md-4 or md-8 or md-12 </div>

just make sure to have always 12 if you sum the numbers up... 

check this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: so should my <div class="row"> replace my <div id="navigation_bar">?